# Lithium Ion battery stopped charging

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have a wireless keyboard that uses rechargeable Lithium-ion battery, the battery is flat and it won't recharge, instead the circuit becomes very hot. I checked the coponents on the circuit for any sign of burns or faults but every thing seems to be fine, the only peice that's heating up is a 6 pins IC labelled `017tL`, i think that it is the battery charge IC, However i couldn't find it on the interent.

This is the circuit and the red line points to the `017tL` IC:

[image]

I couldn't find any schematics for this device and the `017tL` component is not available on Amazon or Ebay, Is there an equivalent replacement part that i can buy?

Comment: It could also be the battery that is bad. Do you have the ability to test the battery by charging/discharging it using  a different charger or some kind of test equipment?

Comment: no i havn't tested the battery but i don't think it's dead because the device is only 5 months old and i charged it only twice using the USB cable from my laptop.

Comment: Something is defective. It could be the battery. I see your point, that it shouldn't yet be worn out because it is relatively  new. But the IC also should not be bad. Anyway, testing the battery would be a good idea only if you can do it easily. If not, then you can try replacing the IC and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That chip looks to be a Seaward Electronics SE9017-LF. "Standalone Linear Lithium Battery Charger". You can download the datasheet from [this](http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/1058/SE9017.php) page.

I found this by googling "017tl ic".  Somehow Google made the link between that part marking and the actual IC part number; I didn't see the "017tl" marking anywhere on the datasheet.

I cannot find this IC from any of my standard distributors in the USA.  It looks like Alibaba has it in high quantity :)  Hopefully you can find someone that will sell in smaller batches.

Comment: Thanks i found another [link](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/-electronic-component-SE9017-LF-017tL_1705032161.html) that says it's 017tL, this should do the job